# java.net.SocketException: connection reset on reading bytes

Tags: java, sockets, socketexception

i am trying to create a little server in java using sockets.
The sockets are connected but when i send data from my client to my server it gives an exception.

stacktrace (UPDATED):

```
    IOException on socket listen: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.codox.game.network.NetworkController$doComms.run(NetworkController.java:81)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

if you need more information tell me

any suggestions are welcome

thx

-- EDITED --

full server code:

```
class doComms implements Runnable
{
    private Socket server;
    PackageHandler packageHandler;
    doComms(Socket server)
    {
        this.server = server;
        packageHandler = new PackageHandler();
    }

    public void run()
    {

        try
        {
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(server.getInputStream());     
            ClientPackage clientPack = (ClientPackage) ois.readObject();

            RespondPackage rp = packageHandler.handlePackage(clientPack);

            ObjectOutputStream ous = new ObjectOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());

            ous.writeObject(rp);
            ous.flush();

            server.close();
            System.out.println("Connection was finished and closed.");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println("IOException on socket listen: " + ioe);
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

full client code:

```
SocketHints hints = new SocketHints();
        hints.keepAlive = true;
        hints.connectTimeout = 2000;

        Socket socket;
        try
        {
            socket = Gdx.net.newClientSocket(Protocol.TCP, "127.0.0.1", 12346, hints);

            ClientPackage client = new ClientPackage();
            client.setRequestType(RequestType.ping);

            ObjectOutputStream ous = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            ous.writeObject(client);
            ous.flush();

            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            RespondPackage response = (RespondPackage) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Respone type = " + response.getRequestType());

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: The sockets are connected but the error says they are not. For further debugging you can try using some tool to monitor network packets. you can try Wireshark

Comment: please share the server code too, the possibility is may you close either output or input streams, so closing the stream(in || out) causes closing the socket.

Comment: post updated with full code

Comment: Why all the ByteArrayInput/OutputStreams? Why not just write the objects directly to the socket? And read them directly from it? Why the PrintWriter? Why test isConnected() at a point where it can't possibly be false?

Comment: @EJP i updated my code so it direclty writes/read objects. but im still getting the connection reset. any suggestions on what it might be?

Comment: You need to edit the stack trace as well. At present it doesn't agree with the code.

Comment: @EJP stacktrace is updated